# How to get Image URL from LinkedIn API using URN?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm following steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin) to upload a LinkedIn post with images.

When an image is uploaded successfully, LinkedIn returns a URN as an identifier for the image. Is there any way to get the image url using the urn?

According to the docs, they have an API `{{baseUrl}}/v2/assets/:assetId` which should return asset for an ID but I'm getting `com.linkedin.vector.utils.logic.LogicLayerException: Invalid asset id` error while calling it.

Also the uploadUrl which is where the image is uploaded is not returning anything meaningful.